# random_score does not work properly with "should"

Tags: elasticsearch

In the following code I always get "Alexander McQueen" products coming first, no matter what I set the seed to.

How can I change my search query to properly shuffle results?

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 99287
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "(adidas originals)",
                      "default_operator": "AND",
                      "fields": [
                        "name^4",
                        "description"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "category": [
                        "Fashion",
                        "Sports",
                        "Other",
                        ""
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "currency": {
                        "term": "USD"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "(alexander mcqueen)",
                      "default_operator": "AND",
                      "fields": [
                        "name^4",
                        "description"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "category": [
                        "Fashion"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "currency": {
                        "term": "USD"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 40,
  "from": 0
}
```

Comment: What happens if you enable [`explain`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) for this request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the random score is being multiplied by the `_score` from the original query.  If you want the results to be purely based on the random score, then set the `boost_mode` to `replace` (instead of the default `multiply`).

See the [`function_score` documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_using_function_score).